Making script compatible to work with other youtube URL format
I am using a script to get video ID from the URL but it fails when the URL format is changed
var url = $(this).attr("href");
 // Get video ID
var video_id = url.split('v=')[1];
var ampersandPosition = video_id.indexOf('&');
if(ampersandPosition != -1) {
  video_id = video_id.substring(0, ampersandPosition);
}
var getvideoid = video_id;

Works ok with https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJwYBJMSbPI but fails when https://youtu.be/poh7M2dLn5U?si=QbJekXikzuxYxAaJ

Maybe parsing the query and check which parameter is there. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

@Death-is-the-real-truth, nope. The youtu.be URL has the ID in the path.

That’s what the question was, likely suggesting to look after the =, but a real solution already exists

You should be able to get these easily by checking the URL's host and changing how you get the ID.
Also, use the URL API when dealing with URLs. It will make it so much easier.
Both these links are for the same video. I assume the si parameter is for tracking purposes.


const getVideoId = (url) => {
  const videoUrl = new URL(url);
  
  if (videoUrl.host === 'youtu.be')
    // trim the leading forward slash
    return videoUrl.pathname.replace(/^\//, '');
    
  else // "standard" format
    return videoUrl.searchParams.get('v')
};

const urls = [
  'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJwYBJMSbPI',
  'https://youtu.be/KJwYBJMSbPI?si=SPo8xXjlUHb3QnI4'];

for (const url of urls)
{
  const videoId = getVideoId(url);
  console.log(`URL: ${url} => Video ID: ${videoId}`);
};




don't think it will work in all cases: https://gist.github.com/rodrigoborgesdeoliveira/987683cfbfcc8d800192da1e73adc486

Wow. I think you might be right.

for the current scenario shared by OP, your code will work fine. so +1
